# Hexadecimal Meaning in Hopper Disassembler iOS Files

Tags: ios, assembly, arm, reverse-engineering, disassembly

When opening certain IOS files such as the kernel (can apply to other situations, just specifying this) a list of hexadecimal values appear on the left on the program (usually Hopper Disassembler). 
What exactly do these values mean for the IOS kernel? If anyone can explain simply that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Probably either addresses or hexdump of the machine code, or both.  I haven't used that disassembler, but that's typical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The first column (blue numbers) represents the addresses of the instructions. In front of each of them, the instruction, and its operands (or arguments).

Like here for iOS 12.1.3(beta 4) kernel:
[image]
The subroutine `sub_fffffff0070750e` starts with the instruction `mov` at the address fffffff00707505e.

Comment: This helped me understand my view on hexadecimal! Can I contact you through anything? I would like to ask more about the IOS Kernel exploitation and reverse engineering. Thanks.